# Java PrintWriter: Writing to the same file over time

Tags: java, file-io, printwriter

I'm making a hangman game and the goal is to save the stats for different players, such as their name, games played, and wins.  I have this part working, but every time I run the program it deletes the previous data and replaces it.

```
public static void writeStats(File file,String name, int won, int games) {
    try {
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(file);
        pw.println("Player\tWon\tTotal");
        pw.println("-----------------------------");
        pw.println(name+"\t"+won+"\t"+games);
        pw.close();
    } //end try
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Failed to write file!");
    } //end catch
} //end method
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to append text to an existing file in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625234/how-to-append-text-to-an-existing-file-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

You can pass `PrintWriter` a `Writer`, and use `FileWriter`, which has an append flag, which will allow you to append the values to the file

Start by having a look at [`FileWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html)

```
try (PrintWriter ps = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(file, true))) {
    //...
} catch (IOException exp) {
    System.out.println("Failed to write file!");
    exp.printStackTrace();
}
```